# C#: Downloading a video file (MP4) results in WebException

Tags: c#, .net

During various downloads, I seem to be getting a "file is already used by another process." when downloading the file at `webClient.DownloadFile` line.

This file hasn't been downloaded before, so how can it be open elsewhere? It seems to only happen when I'm downloading files of type MP4, which is strange.

Exception:

> System.Net.WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient
>   request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the
>   file 'M:\blah\blah\blah' because it is being used by another process.

Code:

```
public static class DownloadUtilities
{
    public static int FailedDownloadCount;

    public static void DownloadLinks(List<AFile> files)
    {
        FailedDownloadCount = 0;

        Parallel.ForEach(
            files,
            new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 },
            currentFile => { DownloadFile(currentFile); }
        );
    }

    private static void DownloadFile(AFile file)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                webClient.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0)");
                webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(file.Address), file.SaveLocation);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Logger.Warn(e.ToString());
        }

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you accessing the webpage from another app?  You can only have one connection to the same IP.  Check using cmd.exe >Netstat -a and see if the connection already exists.

Comment: That's not true, it's downloading the images in parallel which are hosted on the same IP. But just for the record, no I haven't got it open elsewhere.

Comment: Are you sure your files list doesn't have any overlapping save locations?

Comment: I'm calling `Distinct()` on both lists so no, I'm sure.

Comment: Make sure you aren't opening the file more than once.   You can read a file from multiple processes but cannot write to the same file by opening more than once.